# How do I freeze a goal for a list of variables?

Tags: prolog, clpfd, automaton

My ultimate goal is to make a reified version of automaton/3, that freezes if there are any variables in the sequence passed to it. i.e. I dont want the automaton to instantiate variables.

(fd_length/3, if_/3 etc as defined by other people here on so).

To start with I have a reified test for single variables:

```
var_t(X,T):-
  var(X) ->
  T=true;
  T=false.
```

This allows me to implement:

```
if_var_freeze(X,Goal):-
  if_(var_t(X),freeze(X,Goal),Goal).
```

So I can do something like:

```
?-X=bob,Goal =format("hello ~w\n",[X]),if_var_freeze(X,Goal).
```

Which will behave the same as:

```
?-Goal =format("hello ~w\n",[X]),if_var_freeze(X,Goal),X=bob.
```

**How do I expand this to work on a list of variables so that Goal is only called once, when all the vars have been instantiated?**

In this method if I have more than one variable I can get this behaviour which I don't want:

```
?-List=[X,Y],Goal = format("hello, ~w and ~w\n",List),
if_var_freeze(X,Goal),
if_var_freeze(Y,Goal),X=bob.

hello, bob and _G3322
List = [bob, Y],
X = bob,
Goal = format("hello, ~w and ~w\n", [bob, Y]),
freeze(Y, format("hello, ~w and ~w\n", [bob, Y])).
```

I have tried:

```
freeze_list(List,Goal):-
  freeze_list_h(List,Goal,FrozenList),
  call(FrozenList).

freeze_list_h([X],Goal,freeze(X,Goal)).
freeze_list_h(List,Goal,freeze(H,Frozen)):-
  List=[H|T],
  freeze_list_h(T,Goal,Frozen).
```

Which works like:

```
 ?- X=bob,freeze_list([X,Y,Z],format("Hello ~w, ~w and ~w\n",[X,Y,Z])),Y=fred.
 X = bob,
 Y = fred,
 freeze(Z, format("Hello ~w, ~w and ~w\n", [bob, fred, Z])) .

?- X=bob,freeze_list([X,Y,Z],format("Hello ~w, ~w and ~w\n",[X,Y,Z])),Y=fred,Z=sue.
Hello bob, fred and sue
X = bob,
Y = fred,
Z = sue .
```

Which seems okay, but I am having trouble applying it to automaton/3.
To reiterate the aim is to make a reified version of automaton/3, that freezes if there are any variables in the sequence passed to it. i.e. I don't want the automaton to instantiate variables.

This is what I have:

```
ga(Seq,G) :-
    G=automaton(Seq, [source(a),sink(c)],
                     [arc(a,0,a), arc(a,1,b),
                      arc(b,0,a), arc(b,1,c),
                      arc(c,0,c), arc(c,1,c)]).

max_seq_automaton_t(Max,Seq,A,T):-
  Max #>=L,
  fd_length(Seq,L),
  maplist(var_t,Seq,Var_T_List), %find var_t for each member of seq
  maplist(=(false),Var_T_List),  %check that all are false i.e no  uninstaninated vars
  call(A),!,
  T=true.
max_seq_automaton_t(Max,Seq,A,T):-
  Max #>=L,
  fd_length(Seq,L),
  maplist(var_t,Seq,Var_T_List), %find var_t for each member of seq
  maplist(=(false),Var_T_List),  %check that all are false i.e no uninstaninated vars
  \+call(A),!,
  T=false.
max_seq_automaton_t(Max,Seq,A,true):-
  Max #>=L,
  fd_length(Seq,L),
  maplist(var_t,Seq,Var_T_List), %find var_t for each
  memberd_t(true,Var_T_List,true), %at least one var
    freeze_list_h(Seq,A,FrozenList),
  call(FrozenList),
  call(A).
max_seq_automaton_t(Max,Seq,A,false):-
  Max #>=L,
  fd_length(Seq,L),
  maplist(var_t,Seq,Var_T_List), %find var_t for each
  memberd_t(true,Var_T_List,true), %at least one var
    freeze_list_h(Seq,A,FrozenList),
    call(FrozenList),
  \+call(A).
```

Which does not work, The following goal should be frozen until X is instantiated:

```
?- Seq=[X,1],ga(Seq,A),max_seq_automaton_t(3,Seq,A,T).
Seq = [1, 1],
X = 1,
A = automaton([1, 1], [source(a), sink(c)], [arc(a, 0, a), arc(a, 1, b), arc(b, 0, a), arc(b, 1, c), arc(c, 0, c), arc(c, 1, c)]),
T = true
```

*Update* This is what I now have which I think works as I originally  intended but I am digesting what @Mat has said to think if this is actually what I want. Will update further tomorrow.

```
goals_to_conj([G|Gs],Conj) :- 
  goals_to_conj_(Gs,G,Conj).

goals_to_conj_([],G,nonvar(G)).
goals_to_conj_([G|Gs],G0,(nonvar(G0),Conj)) :-
  goals_to_conj_(Gs,G,Conj).

max_seq_automaton_t(Max,Seq,A,T):-
  Max #>=L,
  fd_length(Seq,L),
  maplist(var_t,Seq,Var_T_List), %find var_t for each member of seq
  maplist(=(false),Var_T_List),  %check that all are false i.e no uninstaninated vars
  call(A),!,
  T=true.
max_seq_automaton_t(Max,Seq,A,T):-
  Max #>=L,
  fd_length(Seq,L),
  maplist(var_t,Seq,Var_T_List), %find var_t for each member of seq
  maplist(=(false),Var_T_List),  %check that all are false i.e no uninstaninated vars
  \+call(A),!,
  T=false.
max_seq_automaton_t(Max,Seq,A,T):-
  Max #>=L,
  fd_length(Seq,L),
  maplist(var_t,Seq,Var_T_List), %find var_t for each
  memberd_t(true,Var_T_List,true), %at least one var
  goals_to_conj(Seq,GoalForWhen),
  when(GoalForWhen,(A,T=true)).
max_seq_automaton_t(Max,Seq,A,T):-
  Max #>=L,
  fd_length(Seq,L),
  maplist(var_t,Seq,Var_T_List), %find var_t for each
  memberd_t(true,Var_T_List,true), %at least one var
  goals_to_conj(Seq,GoalForWhen),
  when(GoalForWhen,(\+A,T=false)).
```

Comment: The way I see it is that `if_/3` should not be used like this... Why do you even bother using `if_/3` and not simply write `if_var_freeze(X,Goal) :- ( var(X) -> freeze(X,Goal) ; call(Goal) ).`? Or even simpler: `if_var_freeze(X,Goal) :- freeze(X,Goal).`?

Comment: Please tell us a little more about your use case! What is the difference to, say, using `ground/1` in combination with `automaton/3` and some if-then-else? Assuming, of course, that `automaton/3` always succeeds deterministically or finitely fails when used with ground data...

Comment: I am mainly just trying things out to try and get better at using these methods.  I had an idea about trying to learn automata and grammars, by using a combination of generate and test, alongside constraints. Probably a bit crazy though!

Comment: For if_var_freeze I was trying to find away to apply that to a list of vars for one goal..

Answer (score 4):

In my view, you are making great progress with Prolog. At this point it makes sense to proceed a bit more prudently though. All the things you are asking for can, in principle, be solved easily. You only need a generalization of `freeze/2`, which is available as `when/2`.

However, let us take a step back and more deeply consider what is actually going on here.

Declaratively, when we state a constraint, we mean that *it holds*. We do not mean "It holds only when everything is instantiated", because that would reduce the constraint to a mere checker, leading to a "generate-and-test" approach. The point of constraints is exactly to *prune* whenever possible, leading to a much reduced search space in many cases.

Exactly the same holds for *reified* constraints. When we post a reified constraint, we state that the *reification* holds. Not only in cases where everything is instantiated, but *always*. The point is exactly that the (reified) constraint can be used in all directions. If the constraint that is being reified is already entailed, we get to know it. Likewise, if it cannot hold, we get to know it. If either possibility may be the case, we need to search explicitly for solutions, or determine that none exist. If we want to insist that the constraint that is being reified holds, it is easily possible; etc.

However, the point in all cases is exactly that we can focus on the *declarative* semantics of the constraint, very free from extra-logical, procedural considerations like what is being instantiated and when. If I answered your literal question, it would move you closer to operational considerations, much closer than you probably need or want in actuality.

Therefore, I am not going to answer your literal question. But I will give you a solution to your *actual*, underlying issue.

The point is to *reifiy* `automaton/3`. A constraint reification will not by itself prune anything as long as it is open whether the constraint that is being reified actually holds or not. Only when we *insist* that the constraint that is being reified holds does propagation occur.

It is easy to reify `automaton/3`, by reifying the conjunction of constraints that constitute its decomposition. Here is one way to do it, based on code that is freely available in SWI-Prolog:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

automaton(Vs, Ns, As, T) :-
        must_be(list(list), [Vs,Ns,As]),
        include_args1(source, Ns, Sources),
        include_args1(sink, Ns, Sinks),
        phrase((arcs_relation(As, Relation),
                nodes_nums(Sinks, SinkNums0),
                nodes_nums(Sources, SourceNums0)), [[]-0], _),
        phrase(transitions(Vs, Start, End), Tuples),
        list_to_drep(SinkNums0, SinkDrep),
        list_to_drep(SourceNums0, SourceDrep),
        (   Start in SourceDrep #/\
            End in SinkDrep #/\
            tuples_in(Tuples, Relation)) #<==> T.


include_args1(Goal, Ls0, As) :-
        include(Goal, Ls0, Ls),
        maplist(arg(1), Ls, As).

list_to_drep([L|Ls], Drep) :-
        foldl(drep_, Ls, L, Drep).

drep_(L, D0, D0\/L).

transitions([], S, S) --> [].
transitions([Sig|Sigs], S0, S) --> [[S0,Sig,S1]],
        transitions(Sigs, S1, S).

nodes_nums([], []) --> [].
nodes_nums([Node|Nodes], [Num|Nums]) -->
        node_num(Node, Num),
        nodes_nums(Nodes, Nums).

arcs_relation([], []) --> [].
arcs_relation([arc(S0,L,S1)|As], [[From,L,To]|Rs]) -->
        node_num(S0, From),
        node_num(S1, To),
        arcs_relation(As, Rs).

node_num(Node, Num), [Nodes-C] --> [Nodes0-C0],
        { (   member(N-I, Nodes0), N == Node ->
              Num = I, C = C0, Nodes = Nodes0
          ;   Num = C0, C is C0 + 1, Nodes = [Node-C0|Nodes0]
          ) }.

sink(sink(_)).

source(source(_)).
```

Note that this propagates *nothing whatsoever* as long as `T` is unknown.

I now use the following definition for a few sample queries:

```
seq(Seq, T) :-
        automaton(Seq, [source(a),sink(c)],
                       [arc(a,0,a), arc(a,1,b),
                        arc(b,0,a), arc(b,1,c),
                        arc(c,0,c), arc(c,1,c)], T).
```

Examples:

```
?- seq([X,1], T).
```

Result (omitted): Constraints are posted, nothing is propagated.

Next example:

```
?- seq([X,1], T), X = 3.
X = 3,
T = 0.
```

Clearly, the reified `automaton/3` constraint does *not* hold in this case. However, the *reifying* constraint of course still holds, as always, and this is the reason why `T=0` in this case.

Next example:

```
?- seq([1,1], T), indomain(T).
T = 0 ;
T = 1.
```

Oh-oh! What is going on here? How can it be that the constraint is both true and false? This is because we do not see all constraints that are actually posted in this example. Use `call_residue_vars/2` to see the whole truth.

In fact, try it on the simpler example:

```
?- call_residue_vars(seq([1,1],0), Vs).
```

The pending residual constraints that still need to be satisfied in this case are:

```
_G1496 in 0..1,
_G1502#/\_G1496#<==>_G1511,
tuples_in([[_G1505,1,_G1514]], [[0,0,0],[0,1,1],[1,0,0],[1,1,2],[2,0,2], [2,1,2]])#<==>_G825,
tuples_in([[_G831,1,_G827]], [[0,0,0],[0,1,1],[1,0,0],[1,1,2],[2,0,2],[2,1,2]])#<==>_G826,
_G829 in 0#<==>_G830,
_G830 in 0..1,
_G830#/\_G828#<==>_G831,
_G828 in 0..1,
_G827 in 2#<==>_G828,
_G829 in 0..1,
_G829#/\_G826#<==>0,
_G826 in 0..1,
_G825 in 0..1
```

So, the above only holds *if* these constraints, which are said to still *flounder*, also hold.

Here is an auxiliary definition that helps you label remaining finite domain variables. It suffices for this example:

```
finite(V) :-
        fd_dom(V, L..U),
        dif(L, inf),
        dif(U, sup).
```

We can now paste back the residual program (which consists of CLP(FD) constraints), and use `label_fixpoint/1` to label variables whose domain is finite:

```
?- Vs0 = [_G1496, _G1499, _G1502, _G1505, _G1508, _G1511, _G1514, _G1517, _G1520, _G1523, _G1526],
  _G1496 in 0..1,
  _G1502#/\_G1496#<==>_G1511,
  tuples_in([[_G1505,1,_G1514]], [[0,0,0],[0,1,1],[1,0,0],[1,1,2],[2,0,2], [2,1,2]])#<==>_G825,
  tuples_in([[_G831,1,_G827]], [[0,0,0],[0,1,1],[1,0,0],[1,1,2],[2,0,2],[2,1,2]])#<==>_G826,
  _G829 in 0#<==>_G830, _G830 in 0..1,
  _G830#/\_G828#<==>_G831, _G828 in 0..1,
  _G827 in 2#<==>_G828, _G829 in 0..1,
  _G829#/\_G826#<==>0, _G826 in 0..1, _G825 in 0..1,
  include(finite, Vs0, Vs),
  label(Vs).
```

Note that we cannot directly use labeling in the original program, i.e., we *cannot* do:

```
?- call_residue_vars(seq([1,1],0), Vs), <label subset of Vs>.
```

because `call_residue_vars/2` also brings internal variables to the surface that, although they have a domain assigned and look like regular CLP(FD) variables, are not meant to directly participate in any labeling.

In contrast, the *residual program* can be used without any problem for further reasoning, and it is in fact *meant* to be used that way.

In this concrete case, after labeling the variables whose domains are still finite in the case above, some constraints *still* remain. They are of the form:

```
tuples_in([[_G1487,1,_G1496]], [[0,0,0],[0,1,1],[1,0,0],[1,1,2],[2,0,2],[2,1,2]])#<==>_G1518
```

**Exercise**: Does it follow from this, however indirectly, that the original query, i.e., `seq([1,1],0)`, *cannot hold*?

So, to summarize:

1. Constraint reification does not in itself cause propagation of the constraint that is being reified.
2. Constraint reification often lets you detect that a constraint *cannot* hold.
3. In general, CLP(FD) propagation is necessarily **incomplete**, i.e., we cannot be sure that there is a solution just because our query succeeds.
4. `labeling/2` lets you see whether there are concrete solutions, if domains are finite.
5. To see *all* pending constraints, wrap your query in `call_residue_vars/2`.
6. As long as pending constraints remain, it is only a *conditional* answer.

**Recommendation**: To make sure that no floundering constraints remain, wrap your query in `call_residue_vars/2` and look for any residual constraints on the toplevel.

Comment: If I have `seq2(Seq, T) :-
        automaton(Seq, [source(a),sink(c)],
                       [arc(a,1,b),
   arc(b,1,c)
   ], T).`
I think it exhibits similar behaviour? 
`?- seq2([1,1],T), indomain(T).
T = 0 ;
T = 1.

?- call_residue_vars(seq2([1,1],0),Vs),label_fixpoint(Vs).
Vs = [1, _G6161, 1, 0, _G6170, 1, 1, 0, 0|...].`

Comment: Good! And is it the simplest case?

Comment: I think its to do with the loops in the automaton. So here a successful pass goes from node A to node B consuming the 1. We have started in the source node and ended in the sink node.
But if a pass uses the node A self loop to consume the one. It is not in a sink state, so fails.

seq2(Seq, T) :-
        automaton(Seq, [source(a),sink(b)],
                       [arc(a,1,a),
                        arc(a,1,b)
                        ], T).

?- call_residue_vars(seq2([1],T),Vs),label_fixpoint(Vs).
T = 0,
Vs = [_G1434, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0] ;
T = 1,
Vs = [_G1424, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1].

Comment: Good! 2 nodes and 2 arcs is also the simplest case I found. Now check this out: There seems to be a mistake in how the CLP(FD) library currently handles *reified* `tuples_in/2`. In the case of `automaton/4`, using `?- call_residue_vars(seq([1,1],0), Vs), label_fixpoint(Vs).` yields a *different* result compared to pasting back the residual goals from `?- call_residue_vars(seq([1,1],0),Vs).` and calling `label_fixpoint(Vs)` on the variables from the residual goals! Let's find a simpler case for this and then submit a patch or report!

Comment: I am a bit lost to be honest! 
I can see that:
 `?- call_residue_vars(tuples_in([[Start,1,Stop]],[[0,1,0],[0,1,1]])#<==>T,Vs),label_fixpoint(Vs).
T = 0,
Vs = [Stop, Start, _G20790, 0],
Start#=0#<==>_G20803,
Start#=0#<==>_G20815,
_G20803 in 0..1,
_G20803#/\_G20842#<==>0,
_G20842 in 0..1,
Stop#=1#<==>_G20842,
Stop#=0#<==>_G20875,
_G20875 in 0..1,
_G20815#/\_G20875#<==>0,
_G20815 in 0..1 ;
Start = Stop, Stop = 0,
T = 1,
Vs = [0, 0, _G17336, 1] ;
Start = 0,
Stop = T, T = 1,
Vs = [1, 0, _G17357, 1]. `  but  `56 ?- label_fixpoint([Stop, Start, _G20790, 0]).
true.` is that a case?

Comment: Yes, very good. Meanwhile, I have also looked into this (example: `(A in 0 #/\ tuples_in([[A,1,B]],[[0,0,0],[0,1,1],[1,1,2]])) #<==> 0`) and found that labeling is not meant to be used on all variables that `call_residue_vars/2` brings to the surface. Some of these variables are, in regular queries, not accessible to users, and CLP(FD) relies an them *not* participating explicitly in labeling outside of their dedicated purpose. I will adjust my answer to take this into account. Still, to make sure that no constraints remain, always use `call_residue_vars/2` to see *all* residual goals.

Comment: Thanks for the update. So in general if I just use clpfd constraints and try to reifiy them, in order to check if they hold, I cant guarantee that when they say true, that they actually are true with out having to check for reisdue vars and pulling out the residual program for a specialised labelling routine? CLPFD suddenly seems a lot less useful :S.

Comment: Is this true for clb as well? i.e I cant guarantee that a reified formula is true?

Comment: *Incompleteness* is a fundamental and intrinsic property of all CLP(FD) systems, due to the undecidability of integer arithmetic. So, you *always* need to use `call_residue_vars/2` to see the conditions that make your queries true, also if you are *not* using any reification. CLP(FD) is incomplete in simple cases too: `t :- X #> Y, Y #> X.`. If you ask: `?- t.`, then Prolog will say `true`, but in fact this is false! Always use `call_residue_vars/2` to see the whole truth. CLP(B), in contrast, is *complete* in both SICStus and SWI: If `sat/1` succeeds, then there definitely is a solution too.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations.

Comment: I hope they help you to answer, after some more pondering, the question whether or not we can consider the automaton constraint now satisfied in the case above. It is not as easy as it first appears, and I do not expect you to answer this right away. For now, I only wanted to show you how reification can help you detect that something *certainly* does not hold or *certainly* holds. This is definitely the case if no or only satisfiable residual constraints remain after `call_residue_vars/2`. In the general case, we cannot decide it anyways due to incompleteness and undecidability of arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the widely available [prolog-coroutining](/questions/tagged/prolog-coroutining) predicate `when/2` (for details, consider reading the [SICStus Prolog manual page on `when/2`](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/mpg_002dref_002dwhen.html)).

Note that you can, in principle, implement `freeze/2` like this:

```
freeze(V,Goal) :-
   when(nonvar(V),Goal).
```

Comment: I see I can put: `when((nonvar(X),nonvar(Y)),Goal).` 
But I cant put a list like: `List=[nonvar(X),nonvar(Y),nonvar(Z)],when(List,Goal). ` How does that work?

Comment: What is it that you wish to express? "As soon `X`, `Y`, and `Z` are *all* nonvar, prove goal `G`." ?

Comment: You can have that with `when((nonvar(X),nonvar(Y),nonvar(Z)),Goal)`.

Comment: The first argument of `when/2` is not a list, but a goal composed of nothing but conjunction, disjunction, `nonvar/1`, `ground/1`, and `(?=)/2`.

Comment: Using `(?=)/2` and `when/2` one can implement logically sound term disequality.

Comment: I want to express as soon as all vars in a list are non var prove goal.
How do I construct the first argument of when/2 for a large list of variables?

Comment: Note that there are many, many conjunctions that are equivalent to `A,B,C,D,E`.  So, realistically, we accept that the auxiliary predicate we will use is primarily used in one direction only, that is: given some list of goals  `Gs`, what is one (out of many) conjunction of all goals `G` in `Gs`...

Comment: `vars_to_cond([G|Gs],Cond) :-
   vars_to_cond_(Gs,G,Cond).

vars_to_cond_([],V,nonvar(V)).
vars_to_cond_([V|Vs],V0,(nonvar(V0),Cond)) :-
   vars_to_cond_(Vs,V,Cond).`
Sample uses: `?- vars_to_cond([X],Cond).
Cond = nonvar(X).

?- vars_to_cond([X,Y],Cond).
Cond =  (nonvar(X), nonvar(Y)).

?- vars_to_cond([X,Y,Z],Cond).
Cond =  (nonvar(X), nonvar(Y), nonvar(Z)).`

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by there are many conjunctions equivalent to `A,B,C,D,E` ?  but vars_to_cond/2 works.

Comment: `Goal1,Goal2,Goal3` is actually `(Goal1,(Goal2,Goal3))`.  Executing the conjunction `((Goal1,Goal2),Goal3)` is equivalent, even though it's syntactically different.

Answer (score 1):

What you are implementing appears to me a variation of the following:

```
delayed_until_ground_t(Goal,T) :-
   (  ground(Goal)
   -> (  call(Goal)
      -> T = true
      ;  T = false
      )
   ;  T = true,  when(ground(Goal),once(Goal))
   ;  T = false, when(ground(Goal),  \+(Goal))
   ).
```

Delaying goals *can* be a really nice feature, but be aware of the perils of delaying forever.

Make sure to read and digest the above answer by @mat regarding `call_residue_vars/2`!